# Command Pattern: Where to create the Command items?

Tags: c++, command-pattern

I've used the command pattern quite extensively, and it works well. However, what's usually not discussed is *where* the instances of the Commands are created.

The following examples illustrate this issue: A `Document` has a function `setText()` that sets the text:

```
class Document {
public:
    void setText(const std::string text) {
        if (commandManager()->isActive()) {
            // called by SetTextCommand
            m_text = text;
        } else {
            // called somewhere in the application
            commandManager()->addAndExecute(new SetTextCommand(this, text));
        }
    }
    std::string text() const { return m_text; }

    CommandManager * commandManager() const { return m_commandManager; }
private:
    std::string m_text;
    CommandManager * m_commandManager;
}
```

Here, the `SetTextCommand` would execute `document->setText(text)` like this:

```
class SetTextCommand : public Command {
public:
    SetTextCommand(Document * doc, const std::string & text)
        : Command(), m_doc(doc), m_oldText(doc->text()), m_text(text)
    {}
    void redo() override {
        m_doc->setText(m_text);
    }
    void undo() override {
        m_doc->setText(m_oldText, false);
    }
}
```

The `SetTextCommand` is processed by the `CommandManager` like this:

```
CommandManager::addAndExecute(Command * command) {
    m_doc->commandManager()->setActive(true); // THIS IS THE TRICK
    command->redo();
    m_doc->commandManager()->setActive(false);  // THIS IS THE TRICK
    m_stack->push_back(command);
}
```

The trick here is, that when running `redo()`, `CommandManager::isActive()` is set to *true*. Hence, `Document::setText()` will set `m_text`.

Obviously, all Document setter functions must follow the `if (commandManager()->isActive()) { ... } else { ... }` paradigm. This is, because the Commands themselves are created in the setter functions.

Question is now: **Is this a good way to implement the command pattern? Or are there far cleaner solutions for creating the Commands while at the same time having a nice API?**

Please be verbose with your answers.

Comment: `new SetTextCommand(this, text)` smells of memory leaks

Comment: No, what I omitted is the CommandManager that tracks these items internally in terms of a command stack. This is not an issue at all :)

Comment: addandexecute ? Are you adding and executing the command at once ? What is the point in that ? I would expect a kind of lifo queue of undo commands. These will be executed only when doing an undo.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect more what I mean. Have a look at the class SetTextCommand and how it calls m_doc->setText(). Is the problem more clear now?

Comment: why is setText creating objects? Isn't that violation of SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it'd be pretty ugly to have to replicate the `if (commandManager()->isActive())` everywhere...  probably nicer to have `setText` always do the `SetTextCommand` path, and create a new `setTextImmediate` method which `SetTextCommand` can use.

Comment: Yes, that would probably be better, that hides the work/implementation a bit more behind private functions. However, since you did not criticize the approach or point out a better way to implement this, you are essentially saying: "Yes, that's the way to go." Right?

Comment: He's saying that it's okay as far as creating commands goes, but you should avoid the Active flag.

Comment: I've accepted this answer now, although I'm sure there are still much better ways in doing this... Well, I'll keep my eyes open. :-)